# Cannot load VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

I cannot load VSCOde onto my old Toshiba laptop using Fedoa23. I follow the instructions from the web and finally get the message "No package code availale". I have previously installes VSCode on an old computer using Fedora23 but this time it does not work? Where do I go wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, but this works for me.

You can use these step to install VSCode:

```
sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc

sudo sh -c 'echo -e "[code]\nname=Visual Studio Code\nbaseurl=https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/vscode\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc" > /etc/yum.repos.d/vscode.repo'
```

Then update the package cache and install the package using dnf (Fedora 22 and above):

```
dnf check-update

sudo dnf install code
```

Or on older versions using yum:

```
yum check-update

sudo yum install code
```